# RxJava chain calls lags

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

```
mDisposable = mAdapter.getPublisher()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(new Function<CreateVideoRx, CreateVideoRx>() {

    @Override
    public CreateVideoRx apply(CreateVideoRx createVideoRx) throws Exception {
        Bitmap bitmap = mMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(createVideoRx.time * 1000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, 50, 90);
        createVideoRx.mBitmap = bitmap;
        return createVideoRx;
    }
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Consumer<CreateVideoRx>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(CreateVideoRx createVideoRx) throws Exception {
        createVideoRx.mImageView.setImageBitmap(createVideoRx.mBitmap);
    }
});
```

This RxJava chain works. But I am still doing something wrong because it lags and it does not feel like it is working on a background thread. What will be done in the IO thread in this case and what will be done in the MainThread?

I have done this before with an AsyncTask. It worked fine but now I wanted to skip that and use RxJava instead. The result I have is working but it lags a lot.

**Edit: Added some more information**

```
  private final PublishSubject<CreateVideoRx> mPublisher = PublishSubject.create();
```

Above object is called in the `mAdapter.getPublisher()` and the function itself looks like

```
  public PublishSubject<CreateVideoRx> getPublisher() {
    return mPublisher;
  }
```

What i want to do is to Extract a thumbnail on the background thread. Then when it is done i want it to be pushed to a single ImageView.

Comment: Could be due to a race condition on `createVideoRx`; looks like you share the same instance between multiple threads instead of sending immutable data, like the thumbnail itself to the GUI thread.

Comment: which code blocks do you expect to be done on io thread?

Comment: i was hoping that i could make the first block be executed in the io thread. But noticed this morning that both are executed in main.

Comment: What is `mAdapter.getPublisher()`?

Comment: added some more information

Answer (score 1):

"In RxJava, you can tell your Observable code which thread to run on using `subscribeOn()`, and which thread your Subscriber should run on using `observeOn()`". This is however complicated by the fact that operators subscribe to the source observable.

The way I keep it straight is remember that `subscribeOn()` affects everything upstream of the function while `observeOn` affects everything downstream of the function. What you should have done in the original question is

```
mDisposable = mAdapter.getPublisher()    
.map(new Function<CreateVideoRx, CreateVideoRx>() {

    @Override
    public CreateVideoRx apply(CreateVideoRx createVideoRx) throws Exception {
        Bitmap bitmap = mMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(createVideoRx.time * 1000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, 50, 90);
        createVideoRx.mBitmap = bitmap;
        return createVideoRx;
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Consumer<CreateVideoRx>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(CreateVideoRx createVideoRx) throws Exception {
        createVideoRx.mImageView.setImageBitmap(createVideoRx.mBitmap);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        mDisposable = mAdapter.getPublisher()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Function<CreateVideoRx, CreateVideoRx>() {
                @Override
                public CreateVideoRx apply(CreateVideoRx createVideoRx) throws Exception {
                    Bitmap bitmap = mMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(createVideoRx.time * 1000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
                    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, 50, 90);
                    createVideoRx.mBitmap = bitmap;
                    return createVideoRx;
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<CreateVideoRx>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(CreateVideoRx createVideoRx) throws Exception {
                    createVideoRx.mImageView.setImageBitmap(createVideoRx.mBitmap);
                }
            });
```

This solved my issue. But i still do not understand fully the difference between SubscribeOn and ObserveOn